# YII - Access actionController in modules

Tags: php, frameworks, module, yii

How to call a action controller in module?

I access the url with the address

> "example.com/admin/test"

I've action controller test like this

> protected-modules-admin-controllers-AdminController-actionTest

but the output is

> Error 404 Unable to resolve the request "admin/test".

if i call controller actionTest

> protected-controllers-UserController-actionTest

and i access the url

> "example.com/user/test"

it can, there is no problem

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

I change the index.php to

```
foreach (glob(dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/modules/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $moduleDirectory) {
        $this->setModules(array(basename($moduleDirectory)));
}
return parent::init();
```

and also the main config url

```
'urlManager'=>array(
                        'urlFormat'=>'path',
                        'showScriptName'=>true,
                        'rules'=>array(

                                'admin/<action:\w+>'=>'admin/admin/<action>',
```

likai thanks for the help
now i can access action like yourdomain/admin/admin/test or yourdomain/admin/test :)

Answer (score 1):

`moduleID/controllerID/actionID`

`yourdomain/admin/admin/test`